# PS3 / TP link gigbit switch and sitecom 500 mbps homeplug powerline adaptors

Tags: ps3, powerline-networking

I wonder if someone could help me - give me some pointers.

I get very poor wireless reception in the room i use for my office / ps3 gaming room.

I have a tp link 300 mbps wireless modem router connected to a sitecom homeplug network and then in my office / game room I have the sitecom homeplug connected into a tp link gigabit switch.

I can connect to the internet no problem at all using my macbook with a relatively fast connection and I can also see other devices on my network such as the WD mybook live drive which is downstairs - however my PS3 cannot obtain an ip address when I connect it to the switch - it just times out every time.

I have had it connected previously directly into a 200mbps homeplug and whilst there was a little bit of lag it work fine but as soon as I put it through the switch it just cannot see anything at all - and cannot make any form of connection.

I have a mix of new cat 5e and cat 6 cabling which I have tried plugging into my mac and that has no issues with it but the ps3 just cannot do anything.

I am sure it may just be a settings issue but I am not that technical so am a little unsure about what now to do - could anyone give me any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: You should do a Network trace and check the traffic at the PS3 and at the DHCP Server to track down the issue.